# How to make a bunch of users as default Watchers on all tickets for a JIRA project

Tags: jira

There is a JIRA Project say 'Project Demo'. I would like to add user1, user2, user3... as default watchers on all tickets under 'Project Demo'.

Is it possible. How should I enable it, if yes?

Comment: Perhaps this could help you: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Set-default-watchers-for-a-project/qaq-p/448373

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your project page, select "settings", then select "Autowatch Rules"; this will give you the ability to set up JQL, e.g. "project in ('Project Demo')" and select the users you want to have as automatic watchers.